# Change multiple materials in one GameObject in Unity3D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, sprite, particles

I'll make this short. I have a gameobject and it has a sprite renderer and a particle renderer. What I want to do is, when I give it a command from the script, i want the sprite renderer of the  gameobject to change the material, however if I do it like this :
    using UnityEngine;
    using System.Collections;

```
public class DoorBehav : MonoBehaviour {

public static float DoorHp = 100f;

public TextMesh HpText;
public Material brokenMat; //the material I want to use for the sprite renderer

private GameObject hero;
ParticleEmitter partEmit;

void Start () {
    hero = GameObject.Find("Hero");
    partEmit = GetComponent<ParticleEmitter> ();
    HpText = transform.FindChild ("DoorHp").GetComponent<TextMesh>() as TextMesh;
    HpText.color = Color.green;
}

void Update () {
    if (Vector3.Distance (hero.transform.position, transform.position) < 1.8f)
       {
        HeroBehaviour.agent.speed = 0;
        DoorHp-=1f;
        partEmit.Emit();
        HpText.text = ((Mathf.FloorToInt(DoorHp)).ToString()+"%");

        if(DoorHp <=60f)
        {
            transform.renderer.material = brokenMat;
            HpText.color = Color.yellow;
        }
        if(DoorHp <=30f)
        {
            HpText.color = Color.red;
        }
        if(DoorHp <=0)
        {
            //play sound : destroy door
            HeroBehaviour.agent.speed = HeroBehaviour.moveSpeed; 
            Destroy(this.gameObject);
        }
    }
}
...
```

Basically, this is a door and when the hero gets close to it, it loses hp (hitpoints). If the hp variable is lower than 60, it changes the look of the door to a broken door. However, when I do this, it also changes the material of the particle renderer and it starts spilling out tiny little broken doors instead of the derbis of the broken door. How do I get it to ONLY change the material of the sprite renderer? I've tried countless times but I can't get it to work :(  By the way, I can not add any children to this gameobject, it would mess up many things. Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: showing code like this is not a good example on depicting what the real problem and or issue is ...you need to show also how are you initializing the `MyMaterial` object can you show the Class structure as well as how you are instantiating the object..? basically what I am saying is `Show all relevant code` that pertains to your issue / question at hand thanks

Comment: @DJKRAZE edited and did it like you asked :)

Comment: still looks like a lot of null references based on what I am seeing can't see where you are even setting or newing up this `brokenMat` have you stepped through this code.. to see if something jumps out in regards to what you are seeing vs expected results..?

Comment: As I already said, I get the brokenMat from outside the object, by dragging and dropping it with the Unity3D editor, it is not a null reference because is screws up after I change the sprite renderer material to brokenMat, before that it's all fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a fix myself. Basically, what I did was, I added a ParticleRenderer and got components from the gameobject just like I did with the particle emitter. Then I imported a material just for the particle renderer and after changing the sprite renderer's material, I also changed the particle renderer's:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class DoorBehav : MonoBehaviour {

public static float DoorHp = 100f;

public TextMesh HpText;
public Material brokenMat;
public Material particleMat;//the material for the particle renderer

private GameObject hero;
ParticleEmitter partEmit;
ParticleRenderer partRend;// the new particle renderer

void Start () {
    hero = GameObject.Find("Hero");
    partEmit = GetComponent<ParticleEmitter> ();
    partRend = GetComponent<ParticleRenderer>();//importing the particle renderer
    HpText = transform.FindChild ("DoorHp").GetComponent<TextMesh>() as TextMesh;
    HpText.color = Color.green;
}

void Update () {
    if (Vector3.Distance (hero.transform.position, transform.position) < 1.8f)
       {
        HeroBehaviour.agent.speed = 0;
        DoorHp-=1f;
        partEmit.Emit();
        HpText.text = ((Mathf.FloorToInt(DoorHp)).ToString()+"%");

        if(DoorHp <=60f)
        {
            transform.renderer.material = brokenMat;
            partRend.material = particleMat;//changing the particle renderer's material

            HpText.color = Color.yellow;

        }
        if(DoorHp <=30f)
        {
            HpText.color = Color.red;
        }
        if(DoorHp <=0)
        {

            //play sound : destroy door
            HeroBehaviour.agent.speed = HeroBehaviour.moveSpeed; 
            Destroy(this.gameObject);

        }
    }
}
}
```